# Setting redux state from yield put... take many time

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am facing with React Native, update state from Redux Saga.
   Behind is the code call from Saga just for setting a flag to 'true/false'.
   It take from 3-5 seconds for setting data.

```
    console.log(`Start loading flag...`);
    yield put(authActions.setAuthIsLoading(true));
    yield delay(200);

    endTime = new Date();
    diff = moment.duration(endTime - startTime);
    console.log(`Set loading flag, it take ${diff}...`);
    startTime = endTime;
```

--------------- The result is 5 second

The code of ***authActions.setAuthIsLoading***

```
[types.SET_AUTH_IS_LOADING]: (state, action) => {
        var start = new Date();
        console.log('Set auth busy - Start');
        const { payload } = action;
        let result = state;
        if (state.isLoading !== payload)
        {
            result = state.merge({ isLoading: payload });
        }
        var end = new Date();
        var diff = moment.duration(end-start);
        console.log(`Set auth busy - End - Total: ${diff}(ms)`);    
        return result;
    },
```

---- It just take about some miliseconds (maximum 5 miliseconds)

I really confused that the setting code block function just takes 5 miliseconds, but call via ***yield put(authActions.setAuthIsLoading)***, it comes up to 5 seconds...

Would you please help me on it?

Answer (score 0):

The two code blocks are not comparable. In Redux saga you suspend execution at two points (yield) which means that it can take any amount of time depending on the *other* generators (sagas) being run to return control back to the suspended generator. Once you `yield` it is up to whatever consumes the `yielded` events to decide whether and when to continue consuming from the generator, so a 5 second delay suggests a lot of other code was being given priority.

Additionally a `yield delay(200)` is of course going to make your saga take more time than 5 ms anyway.

This behaviour of generators is why in Redux saga you really, really should not have blocking code anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I understand that delay(200) will take more than 200ms to finish all...
The first code block will yield put and call the action in second code block..
The thing I just wonder that the action job is to too small time (ms) but the actually take so slow (4-5 seconds)? 

May be this issue come by on the same time, other classes access to saga reducer also?

Comment: But that is where the fact that you don't control *when* your generator is consumed comes in. For all I know you have another Redux saga which does a synchronous network request and blocks for 4 seconds... Or perhaps the way Redux sagas are combined implies that this particular one is always dispatched after all the others, that is: it doesn't matter how fast this one is, because again it depends on how quickly the other sagas yield so this one can continue.